# convert string to time javascript in order to have ability to sort it

Tags: javascript, string, date

I need to convert string of format "14.12.22 15:17" to date in order to sort it by seconds. thank you in advance

```js
const toTimestamp = (strDate) => {
    const parsedDate = strDate.split(".");
    const b = parsedDate[2].split(" ");
    const string = `20${b[0]}-${parsedDate[0]}-${parsedDate[1]}T${b[1]}:00`;
    const date = new Date(string).getTime();   
    console.log(string);
    return date;
};

toTimestamp('4.12.22 15:17');
```

Comment: There are no seconds shown in the example date and time. Do you mean you want to sort it from the earliest datetime to the latest datetime?

Comment: yes and no need for seconds

Comment: Once you have the *string* in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` you can sort it as a string - no need to convert to a date. Just make sure to add a leading zero to the MM dd HH mm values to make sure they are two characters each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) after converting the string to ISO 8601 format:

```js
const datestrings = ["14.12.22 15:17", "14.12.22 15:16", "12.12.22 22:22"]
const toTimestamp = (strDate) => {
  const parts = strDate.split(" ")
  const d = parts[0].split(".");
  const t = parts[1]
  const string = `20${d[2]}-${d[1]}-${d[0]}T${t}`;
  const date = Date.parse(string);
  console.log(string, date);
  return date;
}
const dateTimes = []
datestrings.forEach(d => dateTimes.push(toTimestamp(d)))
dateTimes.sort()
console.log(dateTimes)
```

Comment: your string template is better than my quick and dirty concatenation, however to be technically right you're using milliseconds. OP asked for seconds ...

Comment: @RonnieRoyston op said "no need for seconds", it is clear their intent is to sort by date order which this most definitely does.

Comment: it works easily for sure. The challenge here was to manipulate that string to switch the day.month.

Comment: It seems inefficient to parse a string just to construct another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser. Once you have the values, just pass them directly to the *Date* constructor. Consider `let [D,M,Y,H,m] = date.split(/\D/); let tv = +new Date(Y,M-1,D,H,m)` where *tv* is the time value for the associated local date and time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use third-party libraries for parsing the date, e.g., moment.js is one of the famous ones.

Your code can simplified as

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   const momentDate = moment('14.12.22 15:17', 'YY.MM.DD HH:mm');
   console.log(momentDate.toDate());
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Once you have the object you can easily sort on the date object.

Comment: moment is deprecated, please don't suggest to use it while they can just use Date.

Comment: hope you understand that the normal dates cannot work for custom format. I mentioned moment as one of the third party lib, there are others like dayjs and many more. Thanks and have a wonderful day.

Comment: Oh I didn't  see that this format isn't supported directly by "new Date()", my bad.

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow refuses me to remove my downvote until your post is edited...

Comment: @MaximeChéramy I did a small edit for you.

Answer (score -1):

Using dayjs:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)

const toTimestamp = (strDate) => {
  return dayjs(strDate, 'DD.MM.YY HH:mm').unix()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var t = "14.12.22 15:17"
var ts = t.split(" ");
var tss = ts[0].split(".")
var tsss = []
tsss.push(tss[1] + ".")
tsss.push(tss[0] + ".")
tsss.push(tss[2] + " ")
tsss.push(ts[1])
tsss.join();
var d = new Date(tsss);
console.log(d.getTime()/1000);
```

Answer (score -3):

<s>I'm not sure why you are doing all the parsing and re-assembling into an ISO format manually?</s> Without pulling in any libraries like suggested by @Manish Rawat you could do the parsing with a regex, might make it a bit more readable:

```js
// as pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work as expected
// it will interpret the '4' as the month...
//console.log((new Date('4.12.22 15:17')).toISOString())

const toDate = function(str) {
    const rex = /(?<day>\d+).(?<month>\d+).(?<year>\d+)\s+(?<hours>\d+):(?<minutes>\d+):?(?<seconds>\d+)?/;
    const { day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds } = (str.match(rex))?.groups || {
        day: 0,
        month: 0,
        year: 0,
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0
    };
    // console.log(str.match(rex)?.groups, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
    return new Date(`20${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}${seconds ? ':' + seconds : ''}`);
};

console.log(toDate('4.12.22 15:17'), toDate('4.12.22 15:17').getTime());
```

also, from there, what kind of sort are you planning to do? string based i assume? why not convert those dates to actual unix timestamps, e.g. number of seconds and compare those, so you won't have to deal with "weird" javascript string sorting things that might not yield the sort you are expecting?

Comment: have you tried running new Date('14.12.22 15:17') in console and see if that works? it won't right.

Comment: works for me? what do you mean? can't you run the example i posted above in your browser? (maybe it's locale dependent?)

Comment: new Date(Date('14.12.22 15:17')) works, but not directly `new Date`. And this is mysterious for me now

Comment: Look closer at example format "14.12.22 15:17" that's DD.MM.YY needs to convert to YYYY-MM-DD, yours produces YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: the one which you have as an example would work because the you have month as 4. If you were to execute the date "14.12.22 15:17" which OP posted you probably would've encounter error. But again it might be locale dependent, that's why I mentioned in my answer use third party libs and don't invent the wheel again.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy, you answers works for current date

Comment: mmhm, yep, you are right, month is not interpreted properly with only new Date()

Comment: @MaximeChéramy Date seems like a function which just returns the current time. It's not for parsing.

Comment: oh, so it works today. :D

Comment: yes you got it.

Comment: Updated with method that should work.